# Problem with custom user meta field

Tags: customization, users

I've recently added a new field into the User Profile section of my blog So that I may define the gender of the user.

On the author bio section I have this code:

```
$authorgender = strtolower(get_the_author_meta('gender'));

if ($authorgender = "male") {
    $genderoutput = "his";
} else {
    $genderoutput = "her";
    };'
```

And the place i'm using it is:

```
  <p><a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_author(); ?>'s website (new window)">Check out <?php echo $genderoutput; ?> website</a>
```

I have two users, One myself which I changed the gender to 'Male' and one a random woman called sally-louise-fredericke-swann and her gender was set to 'Female'.

However, the $genderoutput generates 'his' for both users. Not happy :/

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($authorgender = "male") {
```

Needs to be

```
if ($authorgender == "male") {
```

== is a comparison operator http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

= assigns the value to the variable http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Holy crap, im so tired and thank you very much! more caffeine needed me thinks - never a good idea to try and code after a 10 hour shift in a restaurant.